# Black and white beads on a circle

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ beads placed on a circle, $n\ge 3$. They are numbered in random order as viewed clockwise. Beads for which the number of the previous bead is less than the number of a next bead are painted in white color,and others - in black.

Two colourations that can be made equal by rotation are considered identical. How many different colourations can occur?

I've write a programm and for $n=3...11$ I've got answers $2 , 1 , 6 , 7 ,  18 , 25 , 58 , 93 , 186$

Comment: The question isn’t entirely clear. Suppose that the beads are in (circular) order $\langle 1,3,2,4\rangle$; is the $2$ bead white (because $3<4$), or is it black (because $3>2$)? According to what you wrote, it’s white, but if that’s the intended interpretation, there is only one possible coloration for $n=4$: BBWW. And under the other interpretation I count four colorations: WWWB, WWBB, WBWB, and WBBB.

Comment: First is black(becouse 4>3).Second-white(1<2).Third-white(3<4).Fourth-black(2>1)

Comment: Okay; that’s what I thought. In that case the only coloration for $n=4$ is BBWW: there’s just one. And for $n=3$ there are just two, WBB and WWB.

Comment: For n=3 we also have coloration BBB (1 1 1 for example) . For n=4 we have BBWW,BBBB,BBBW,BWBW,WWWB

Comment: By *numbered in random order* I understood that they were given the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ in some random circular permutation. Do you mean that they can be given *any* $n$ numbers, possibly with repetition?

Comment: Oh , I'm sorrry .You are right .

Comment: In that case the answers for $n=3,4,5$ are $2,1,6$, if I’ve not made any mistakes; the possibilities are WWB, WBB; WWBB; WWWWB, WWWBB, WWBBB, WWBWB, WBWBB, WBBBB.

Comment: Seems , that you are right . Can you find formula or give some ideas how I can find it?

Comment: That’s going to take some thought; I don’t see any obvious approach, but I haven’t really worked at it yet. I do plan to think about it some more later today when I have more time.

Comment: Have you tried with $3$ or $4$ beads yourself?

Comment: Yes, for 3 answer is 2, for 4 answer is 2 too.

Comment: for $4$ the answer is $3$ consider the sequences 1234,1324,4321. All of them induce distinct cycles.

Comment: @Jorge Fernández, in your examples for 4, 1234 and 1324 this is one necklace, because 1234 - wbbw and 1324 - wbbw (b,w this are black and white beads in  necklace).

Comment: 1234 should be wbbb

Comment: @JorgeFernández, you are not right, because 3>1 and It follows that the last beads in the necklace this "w".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of configurations for this problem
and let $b_n$ be the number of two-colored necklaces with $n$ beads (no flips allowed).
It is well-known that $b_n=\frac 1n\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)2^\frac nd$ (this is OEIS A000031).

Computer runs suggest that for odd $n$ all these patterns also occur for this problem,
except the two monochromatic ones, so $a_n=b_n-2$.

They also suggest that for even $n$ all patterns occur except the ones where one color occurs every second spot.
In this case the number of necklaces where black occurs every second spot is $b_{\frac n2}$.
We get the same number for the patterns where white occurs every second spot,
and then we have double counted the one pattern where black and white alternate all around the necklace,
so we get $a_n=b_n-2b_{\frac n2}+1$.

For the proof of these observations we look at the cases of even $n$ and odd $n$ separately.

First we prove the case for even $n$. Note that in this case the odd beads and the even beads
form two disjoint circular sequences. The colors on the odd beads prescribe the ordering on the even beads (and v.v.),
but there is a huge amount of freedom in assigning the values, and what is more important:
the value assignments on the subsequences are independent: any value assignment on the
odd beads consistent with the colors on the even beads can be combined with any value assignment
on the even beads that is consistent with the colors on the odd beads (as long as no values are
duplicated).

We first show that for any non-monochromatic color sequence on the odd beads we can find a value assignment
for the even beads that is consistent with it. Let $n=2t$ and let $p_1,\ldots,p_t$ be the odd beads
and $q_1,\ldots,q_t$ the even beads, so that the complete necklace is $p_1,q_1,p_2,q_2,\ldots$.

Because the color sequence is not monochromatic and because we have cyclic arrangements
we may assume that $p_1$ is black and $p_2$ is white.
We give $q_1$ the value 1. Now assume we have assigned a value to $q_i$.
If $p_{i+1}$ is white, we assign value $q_i+n$ to $q_{i+1}$, otherwise
we assign value $q_i-1$.
Because we have less than $n$ values to assign this we end up in $q_t$ having a larger value than $q_1$,
which shows that indeed all value assignments on the even beads are consistent with the colors on the odd beads.

We can similarly find a value assignment for the odd beads consistent with the colors on the even beads
(just make sure to use a different range of numbers).

Combining these value assignments and 'flattening' the values to make the valueset equal to $1,\ldots,n$
finishes the proof that for even $n$ any color sequence that is not monochromatic on the odd beads
or the even beads is realizable.

Now we turn to the case that $n$ is odd. In this case we take $n=2t-1$ and we consider the
beads to be numbered $p_1,p_{t+2},p_2,p_{t+3},\ldots,p_n,p_{t+1}$. Since we have excluded
monochromatic patterns we may again assume that $p_1$ is black and $p_2$ is white.
We use the same procedure. We start with value 1 on $p_{t+1}$ and assuming we have
assigned a value to $p_i$ we assign value $p_i+n$ to $p_{i+2}$ if the bead after $p_i$ is white
and value $p_i-1$ if the bead after $p_i$ is black.
This will eventually assign a value to $p_n$ that is larger than 1, so again we have managed
a value assignment consistent with the colors.

Btw, the values found by computer simulation were (starting with $n=3$)
2, 1, 6, 7, 18, 25, 58, 93, 186, 325
which coincides with the given formulas and with the values reported in the question.

Comment: First formula $(a_n=b_n−2.)$ is realy working but seems that second formula have mistake (it's not workind for examples what I've counted using program) . Or may be I can't understand how it works .

Comment: Oh , I'm sorry . Seems that you are right .

Comment: After a night's sleep I could considerably simplify the proof. Now the cases are probably small enough to produce a full proof, which I will try later today.

Comment: I've given a simple, almost no-cases proof in a separate answer.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, I found it as well

Answer (score 5):

What follows  is not  an answer but  a conjecture and  some additional
material. We  start by working  with permutations. I assumed  that the
bit  pattern  /  black-white  pattern  at position  $q$  reflects  the
less-than  greater-than relation  at position  $q$ in  the permutation
(whether the  pair at $q$  and $q+1$ is  an ascent or a  descent, with
circular wrap-around).

I  wrote   a  Perl  program  to  investigate   these  necklaces  (Perl
aficionados are invited to verify  and improve this work, e.g. the bit
strings can be produced with **pack/unpack**). The program
iterates  over  all bit  patterns  and  attempts  to find  a  circular
permutation  that fits  the  pattern using  a backtracking  algorithm,
which I hope I've implemented correctly.

The program produced the following table:

```
$ time ./blg2.pl 12 2>/dev/null
3: 4 2/2
4: 6 4/2
5: 8 6/2
6: 14 12/2
7: 20 18/2
8: 36 34/2
9: 60 58/2
10: 108 106/2
11: 188 186/2
12: 352 350/2

real    7m9.188s
user    7m7.926s
sys     0m0.045s
```

This table shows the total number of circular colorations obtained and
indicates furthermore that for all  $n$ all possible bit patterns were
realized except two. The totals give the sequence

$$4,6,8,14,20,36,60,108,188,352,\ldots $$

which is  [OEIS A00031](https://oeis.org/A000031) which  is simply the
substituted cycle index of the cyclic group
$$\left.Z(C_n)(A+B)\right|_{A=1,B=1},$$
and can be  taken as evidence that the program is  working since it is
the  correct  answer  (total  number  of circular  patterns  with  two
colors.)

Observe that the exact values which are
$$2,4,6,12,18,34,58,106,186,350,\ldots $$
also have an OEIS entry namely
[OEIS A052823](https://oeis.org/A052823)
which  reflects  the underlying  necklace  combinatorics  but not  the
permutation aspect.

The   program  can  also   output  permutations   that  fit   a  given
pattern. Here are the examples for $n=3,4,5$ and $n=6$:

```
$ time ./blg2.pl 5
100 3-1-2
110 3-2-1
111 FAIL
000 FAIL
3: 4 2/2
1010 3-1-4-2
1000 4-1-2-3
1110 4-3-2-1
1100 4-2-1-3
1111 FAIL
0000 FAIL
4: 6 4/2
11100 5-3-2-1-4
11110 5-4-3-2-1
10100 4-1-5-2-3
11010 4-2-1-5-3
11000 5-2-1-3-4
10000 5-1-2-3-4
00000 FAIL
11111 FAIL
5: 8 6/2
100000 6-1-2-3-4-5
111000 6-3-2-1-4-5
101000 5-1-6-2-3-4
110100 5-2-1-6-3-4
100100 4-1-5-6-2-3
111110 6-5-4-3-2-1
110000 6-2-1-3-4-5
110110 4-2-1-6-5-3
111100 6-4-3-2-1-5
101010 3-1-5-4-6-2
111010 5-3-2-1-6-4
101100 4-1-6-5-2-3
111111 FAIL
000000 FAIL
6: 14 12/2
```

Studying the  examples we immediately  have a conjecture,  namely that
all black-white  patterns can be  realized except the  monochrome ones
(this is obvious  as the circularity makes it  impossible to have just
one run in a circular permutation since not all $n$ elements can be to
the left  of a larger/smaller  element).  The conjectured  formula is
thus

$$-2 + \left.Z(C_n)(A+B)\right|_{A=1,B=1}.$$
This is
$$-2 + 
\left.\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) (A^d+B^d)^{n/d}\right|
_{A=1, B=1}.$$

This gives the following 
**CONJECTURE:**
$$\large{\color{#0A0}{
-2 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) 2^{n/d}}}.$$

**Concluding  remark.**  With  the  amount  of data  and  context  now
available it should not be difficult to produce a combinatorial proof,
which I suspect will turn out to be *simple*.

This is the Perl code that was used to compute the above data.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub search {
    my($n, $bits, $q, $avail, $key, $seen, $sofar) = @_;

    if($q==$n){
        if(($bits->[$n-1] == 0 &&
            $sofar->[$n-1] < $sofar->[0]) ||
           ($bits->[$n-1] == 1 &&
            $sofar->[$n-1] > $sofar->[0])){
            $seen->{$key} = join('-', @$sofar);
        }

        return;
    }

    my $pos = 0;
    while(!exists($seen->{$key}) && $pos<$n-$q){
        my $nxttry = $avail->[$pos];

        if($q==0 || 
           (($bits->[$q-1] == 0 && 
             $sofar->[$q-1] < $nxttry) ||
            ($bits->[$q-1] == 1 && 
             $sofar->[$q-1] > $nxttry))){
            push @$sofar, $nxttry;
            splice @$avail, $pos, 1;

            search($n, $bits, $q+1, 
                   $avail, $key, $seen, $sofar);

            splice @$avail, $pos, 0, $nxttry;
            pop @$sofar;
        }

        $pos++;
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = shift || 6; 

     for(my $n=3; $n<=$mx; $n++){
         my $seen = {};  my $failed = {};

         for(my $ind=0; $ind<2**$n; $ind++){
             my $bits = [];

             for(my ($pos, $indx)=(0, $ind); 
                 $pos<$n; $pos++){
                 push @$bits, ($indx %2);
                 $indx = ($indx-$bits->[-1])/2;
             }

             my $rot;
             for($rot=0; $rot<$n; $rot++){
                 my @rotbits =
                     (@$bits[$rot..($n-1)],
                      @$bits[0..($rot-1)]);
                 my $rotkey = join('', @rotbits);

                 last if
                     exists($seen->{$rotkey}) ||
                     exists($failed->{$rotkey});
             }

             if($rot==$n){
                 my $key = join('', @$bits);
                 search($n, $bits, 0, [1..$n], $key, $seen, []);

                 $failed->{$key} = 'FAIL' 
                     if !exists($seen->{$key});
             }
         }

         my $total = scalar(keys %$seen) + scalar(keys %$failed);

         foreach my $pat (keys %$seen){
             print STDERR "$pat " . $seen->{$pat} . "\n";
         }
         foreach my $pat (keys %$failed){
             print STDERR "$pat " . $failed->{$pat} . "\n";
         }

         print "$n: $total " . scalar(keys(%$seen)) . "/" .
             scalar(keys(%$failed)) . "\n";
     }
}
```

There is a radically simplified  version of the above program which is
not  as fast,  however. Instead  of  iterating over  bit patterns  and
backtracking  to  find a  matching  permutation  we  iterate over  all
permutations and collect the  bit patterns / black-white patterns that
appear. The slow-down in the speed  when solving the case of $n=10$ is
on the order of a factor  of $60$. This code uses the factorial number
system to iterate over permutations  and never allocates more than one
permutation at a time.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub fact { 
    my ($n) = @_;

    return 1 if ($n == 0 || $n == 1);
    return $n*fact($n-1);
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = shift || 6; 

     for(my $n=3; $n<=$mx; $n++){
         my $seen = {};

         for(my $ind=0; $ind<fact($n); $ind++){
             my @perm = (1..$n);

             for(my ($pos, $indx) = ($n-1, $ind);
                 $pos > 0; $pos--){
                 my $targ = $indx % ($pos+1);
                 $indx = ($indx-$targ)/($pos+1);

                 my $tmp = $perm[$pos];
                 $perm[$pos] = $perm[$targ];
                 $perm[$targ] = $tmp;
             }

             my @bits = ();

             for(my $pos=0; $pos<$n-1; $pos++){
                 my $bit = 
                     ($perm[$pos] < $perm[$pos+1] ? 1 : 0);
                 push @bits, $bit;
             }
             push @bits, ($perm[$n-1] < $perm[0] ? 1 : 0);

             my $rot;
             for($rot=0; $rot<$n; $rot++){
                 my @rotbits =
                     (@bits[$rot..($n-1)],
                      @bits[0..($rot-1)]);
                 my $rotkey = join('', @rotbits);

                 last if exists($seen->{$rotkey});
             }

             if($rot==$n){
                 my $key = join('', @bits);
                 $seen->{$key} = join('-', @perm);
             }
         }

         foreach my $pat (keys %$seen){
             print STDERR "$pat " . $seen->{$pat} . "\n";
         }

         print "$n: " . scalar(keys(%$seen)) . "\n";
     }
}
```

Comment: In response to your comment, proofs are always simple in retrospect. I find coding is a worthwhile activity and any math enthusiast should master at least a couple of programming languages in addition to a one of the major computer algebra systems.

Comment: You seem to have solved the wrong problem. The question indeed is rather ambiguous, but the comments to the question suggest that it is really about the order of $q,q+2$, not about the order of $q,q+1$.

Comment: Yes ,  it's realy good idea , but you don't understand question . Can you try to do the same for case when we are choosing  color of bead in position $q$  using numbers of beads on positions $q-1$ and $q+1$

Answer (score 4):

The facts observed in [the answer by Leen Droogendijk](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/979852/18880) can easily be explained. I recall that it says that for odd$~n$ all colour patters except the monochromatic (all-white or all-black) ones can be obtained, and for even $n$ all patters except those where either the odd-position or the even-position subsequences are monochromatic (and possibly both simultaneously).

Since one is not counting the actual numberings of the beads, let us start with a given colouring and try to see if the conditions it gives on the associated permutation (which are a collection of inequalities among pairs of permutation entries) are contradictory (in which case the colouring is rejected) or not. It is easy to see that a collection of inequalities is contradictory if it contains any oriented cycles, and consistent otherwise. (Formally, in the latter case the inequalities define by transitivity a partial ordering among the positions of the entries, and partial orderings can always be extended to a total ordering; this prescribes a permutation.)

Now starting at the first bead, write down the colour of *every other bead* (so starting with positions $1$, $3$, $5$,...) wrapping back to the beginning of the necklace at the end, and continuing until bead $1$ is encountered again. If $n$ is odd this happens when all beads have been seen (and two tours of the necklace are completed) while if $n$ is even it happens after the first tour, after which all odd-position beads have been seen. In the latter case similarly make a separate tour for the even-position beads. So we have one or two cyclic chains of colours (according as $n$ is odd or even), and what we wish to show is that the colouring is contradictory if and only if at least one of those chains is monotonic.

Between each pair of successive colours (in cyclic order) of one chain we can place the permutation entry (position) whose value is involved in the both inequalities for those colours. (For instance if the first chain starts BW... then between the B and the W is placed permutation entry $p_2$, which is involved in the inequality $p_n>p_2$ for the black bead coming from position$~1$ and in the inequality $p_2<p_4$ for the white bead coming from position$~3$.) Thus the permutation entries are arranged in one or two cyclic chains linked by inequalities, and all required inequalities are thus taken into account. As observed above the inequalities are contradictory if they are all of the same kind (all "$<$" or all "$>$"; either gives an oriented cycle), and else non-contradictory.

Comment: Sorry, I only saw your comment (and solution) after I finished editing. We seem to have arrived at the same sort of proof.

Answer (score 2):

In response to  the clarification / explanation in  the comments to my
other post  I am sending a  modified version of my  initial program to
account  for  the fact  that  the bit  at  position  $q$ reflects  the
ordering  of the  beads  at  position $q-1$  and  $q+1$ with  circular
wrap-around.

The result  is the following  sequence which I  could not find  in the
OEIS.

```
$ time ./blg-nb.pl 11 2>/dev/null
2
1
6
7
18
25
58
93
186

real    2m48.880s
user    2m42.802s
sys     0m0.062s
```

Here it is for easy inspection once more:
$$2,1,6,7,18,25,58,93,186,\ldots$$

It is  remarkable that for  odd $n$ these  values agree with  the case
where  the bit  at $q$  indicates the  ordering of  positions  $q$ and
$q+1.$

Some examples that one can check with pen-and-paper and thereby verify
the correctness of the program:

```
$ time ./blg-nb.pl 7
100 2-1-3
110 3-1-2
2
1100 2-3-1-4
1
11100 3-4-1-2-5
11110 5-2-4-1-3
10100 2-3-4-1-5
11010 5-1-3-4-2
11000 4-1-2-3-5
10000 3-1-4-2-5
6
100100 2-3-4-5-1-6
110000 3-4-1-5-2-6
110110 3-4-2-6-1-5
111100 3-5-2-4-1-6
101100 2-4-5-3-1-6
111000 3-5-1-4-2-6
110100 3-4-2-5-1-6
7
1011000 3-4-6-1-5-2-7
1011100 2-4-6-3-5-1-7
1010100 2-4-5-3-6-1-7
1010000 3-4-5-1-6-2-7
1111100 4-6-2-5-1-3-7
1101000 6-1-3-4-2-5-7
1111110 7-3-6-2-5-1-4
1100100 3-4-1-5-6-2-7
1000000 4-1-5-2-6-3-7
1101010 7-1-4-5-3-6-2
1111000 5-6-2-3-1-4-7
1101100 4-5-2-6-1-3-7
1111010 7-2-5-1-4-6-3
1001000 4-1-6-2-5-3-7
1110000 4-5-1-2-6-3-7
1110100 3-5-1-4-6-2-7
1110110 3-5-1-4-7-2-6
1100000 5-1-2-3-6-4-7
18

real    0m0.272s
user    0m0.109s
sys     0m0.077s
```

This is the modified version of the program.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub search {
    my($n, $bits, $q, $avail, $key, $seen, $sofar) = @_;

    if($q==$n){
        my $admit = 0;

        if(($bits->[$n-1] == 0 &&
            $sofar->[$n-2] < $sofar->[0]) ||
           ($bits->[$n-1] == 1 &&
            $sofar->[$n-2] > $sofar->[0])){
            $admit++;
        }
        if(($bits->[0] == 0 &&
            $sofar->[$n-1] < $sofar->[1]) ||
           ($bits->[0] == 1 &&
            $sofar->[$n-1] > $sofar->[1])){
            $admit++;
        }

        $seen->{$key} = join('-', @$sofar)
            if $admit == 2;

        return;
    }

    my $pos = 0;
    while(!exists($seen->{$key}) && $pos<$n-$q){
        my $nxttry = $avail->[$pos];

        if($q < 2 ||
           (($bits->[$q-1] == 0 && 
             $sofar->[$q-2] < $nxttry) ||
            ($bits->[$q-1] == 1 && 
             $sofar->[$q-2] > $nxttry))){
            splice @$avail, $pos, 1;
            $sofar->[$q] = $nxttry;

            search($n, $bits, $q+1, 
                   $avail, $key, $seen, $sofar);

            $sofar->[$q] = -1;
            splice @$avail, $pos, 0, $nxttry;
        }

        $pos++;
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = shift || 6; 

     for(my $n=3; $n<=$mx; $n++){
         my $seen = {};

         for(my $ind=0; $ind<2**$n; $ind++){
             my $bits = [];

             for(my ($pos, $indx)=(0, $ind); 
                 $pos<$n; $pos++){
                 push @$bits, ($indx %2);
                 $indx = ($indx-$bits->[-1])/2;
             }

             my $rot;
             for($rot=0; $rot<$n; $rot++){
                 my @rotbits =
                     (@$bits[$rot..($n-1)],
                      @$bits[0..($rot-1)]);
                 last if
                     exists($seen->{join('', @rotbits)});
             }

             if($rot==$n){
                 my $key = join('', @$bits);
                 my $sofar = [(-1) x $n];

                 search($n, $bits, 0, [1..$n], $key, 
                        $seen, $sofar);
             }
         }

         foreach my $pat (keys %$seen){
             print STDERR "$pat " . $seen->{$pat} . "\n";
         }

         print scalar(keys %$seen) . "\n";
     }
}
```

**Addendum.** What we see in the above is the problem of iterating in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ space over all unique necklaces of $n$ beads with $k$ colors without checking all $k^n$ assignments. Commentary and algorithms for this would be most welcome.

**Addendum II.** By removing list splicing from the backtracking code I was able to compute the next value, which is $325.$ I might post this if I manage to compute a second additional value.

**Addendum III  Oct 19 2014.** The  speed-up gained by  not using list
splicing  and  some  other  optimizations  among  them  not  searching
necklaces  that  have  already  been  seen not  to  admit  a  matching
permutation made it  possible to calculate two additional  values in a
reasonable amout of time. Here is the list.

Good to see the problem has been solved, maybe the data from the  Perl
program were useful here.

```
$ time ./blg-nb4.pl 14 2>/dev/null
2
1
6
7
18
25
58
93
186
325
630
1143

real    148m49.703s
user    133m49.043s
sys     0m4.710s
```

This is the improved program.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub search {
    my($n, $bits, $q, $avail, $key, $seen, $sofar) = @_;

    if($q==$n){
        my $admit = 0;

        if(($bits->[$n-1] == 0 &&
            $sofar->[$n-2] < $sofar->[0]) ||
           ($bits->[$n-1] == 1 &&
            $sofar->[$n-2] > $sofar->[0])){
            $admit++;
        }
        if(($bits->[0] == 0 &&
            $sofar->[$n-1] < $sofar->[1]) ||
           ($bits->[0] == 1 &&
            $sofar->[$n-1] > $sofar->[1])){
            $admit++;
        }

        $seen->{$key} = join('-', @$sofar)
            if $admit == 2;

        return;
    }

    my @possibles = keys %$avail;

    my $pos = 0;
    while(!exists($seen->{$key}) && $pos<$n-$q){
        my $nxttry = $possibles[$pos];

        if($q < 2 ||
           (($bits->[$q-1] == 0 && 
             $sofar->[$q-2] < $nxttry) ||
            ($bits->[$q-1] == 1 && 
             $sofar->[$q-2] > $nxttry))){
            delete $avail->{$nxttry};
            $sofar->[$q] = $nxttry;

            search($n, $bits, $q+1, 
                   $avail, $key, $seen, $sofar);

            $sofar->[$q] = -1;
            $avail->{$nxttry} = 1;
        }

        $pos++;
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $mx = shift || 6; 

     for(my $n=3; $n<=$mx; $n++){
         my $seen = {}; my $failed = {};

         my $bits = [(0) x $n];
         for(my $ind=0; $ind<2**$n; $ind++){
             my $rot;
             for($rot=0; $rot<$n; $rot++){
                 my @rotbits =
                     (@$bits[$rot..($n-1)],
                      @$bits[0..($rot-1)]);

                 my $key = join('', @rotbits);
                 last if
                     exists($seen->{$key}) ||
                     exists($failed->{$key});

             }

             if($rot==$n){
                 my $key = join('', @$bits);
                 my $sofar = [(-1) x $n];

                 my %initavail;
                 @initavail{(1..$n)} = (1 x $n);

                 search($n, $bits, 0, \%initavail, $key, 
                        $seen, $sofar);

                 $failed->{$key} = 'FAIL'
                     if !exists($seen->{$key});
             }

             my $pos = 0;

             while($pos<$n && $bits->[$pos] == 1){
                 $bits->[$pos++] = 0;
             }
             $bits->[$pos] = 1;
         }

         foreach my $pat (keys %$seen){
             print STDERR "$pat " . $seen->{$pat} . "\n";
         }

         print scalar(keys %$seen) . "\n";
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let $a_n$ be the number of configurations for this problem
and let $b_n$ be the number of two-colored necklaces with $n$ beads (no flips allowed).
It is well-known that $b_n=\frac 1n\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)2^\frac nd$ (this is OEIS A000031).

Computer runs suggest that for odd $n$ all these patterns also occur for this problem,
except the two monochromatic ones, so $a_n=b_n-2$.

They also suggest that for even $n$ all patterns occur except the ones where one color occurs every second spot.
In this case the number of necklaces where black occurs every second spot is $b_{\frac n2}$.
We get the same number for the patterns where white occurs every second spot,
and then we have double counted the one pattern where black and white alternate all around the necklace,
so we get $a_n=b_n-2b_{\frac n2}+1$.