# Number of restricted ways to two-color a necklace

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ beads placed on a circle, $n\ge 3$. They are numbered in random order as viewed clockwise. Beads for which the number of the previous bead is less than the number of a next bead are painted in white color,and others - in black.

Two colorations that can be made equal by rotation are considered identical. How many different colorations can occur?

Comment: This is repeated [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965292/black-and-white-beads-on-a-circle)

Comment: Solution is at the other copy of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965292/black-and-white-beads-on-a-circle?lq=1

Comment: @Andrew: **Please** un-accept the currently accepted answer (which is a shameless copy of the one Leen Droogendijk mentions in the previous comment) so that that answer can be subsequently deleted (and this question can closed as a duplicate).