# How many different circular necklaces containing ten beads can be made using beads of at most two colors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, necklace-and-bracelets

> How many different circular necklaces containing ten beads can be made using beads of at most two colors?

I know I need calculate situation with 2 colors, 8 second color, 3 first color, 7 second color, 4 first color, 6 second color and 5 first color, 5 second color.

But I have problems with my calculations:

$$\frac{1}{20}\left(\frac{10!}{8!2!} + 3\times 5 + 1\times 5 + 3\times 15\right) = \frac{110}{20}. $$

Please  show to me how to solve this problem correctly.

Comment: Are the colors fixed? Also you are missing the cases where you have $1$ of the first color and where you have $0$ of the first color. Could you be a little more elaborative with your work. I'm struggling to follow your approach.

Comment: Have you looked at the related questions?

Comment: Yes i looked, nothing find.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015418/number-of-necklaces-of-beads-in-two-colors). See also [OEIS A000029](https://oeis.org/A000029) and [OEIS A000031](https://oeis.org/A000031).